# Bullet Shooting On Target Algorithm - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, 2d, projectile

I am making a game where you can shoot. I am having a problem with my algorithm, the bullet is pointing in the direction of the mouse but not moving towards it. Can you please provide me with a better algorithm and tell me why mine does not work? All of this code is in Java. ***BTW the class MImage is a class that I made so don't get confused by it.***  `

```
private double angle;
    public Bullet(int xx, int yy, int x, int y,Gun gun, int id, double angle) {
        this.x = xx;
        this.y = yy;
        tx = x;
        ty = y;
        xorg = xx;
        yorg = yy;
        this.gun = gun;
        this.id = id;
        this.angle = angle;


        try {
            image = new MImage(ImageIO.read(new File("PATH")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        image.rotateBy((int)Math.toDegrees(angle));

        stopwatch.start();
    }



    private int speed = 3,time = 0;;
        public void update() {


            double speedy, speedx;
            speedy = speed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
            speedx = speed * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));

             y = (int) ((-5) * time * time + speedy * time + yorg);
             x = (int) (speedx * time + xorg);
             time++;

             System.out.println(y + " --- " + x);
            if(stopwatch.getElapsedTime() > 500) {
                terminate(id);
            }
        }
```

`

And here is when i make a new instance of the class

```
public boolean shoot(int x, int y, int tx, int ty) {
    boolean worked = false;
    if(amo >= 0) {
        bullets.add(new Bullet(x,y,tx,ty,this,bullets.size(),Math.atan2(ty-y,tx-x)));
        amo --;
        worked = true;
    }
    return worked;
}
```

***THANK YOU***

Comment: Are you sure the Unity3D tag is appropriate for this question? I don't see any relationship between this and the Unity game engine.

Comment: No but so people can see my question. And this is about game development so at some point you might want to use this algorithm in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. The Algorithm is not hard at all, but it's not perfect but still works. It's simple Trigonometry... if you let `angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx)` then `velocityX = speed*Math.cos(angle)` and let `velocityY = speed*Math.sin(angle)` then in the update function put this code `x += velocityX y+= velocityY`